# R markdown using ggvis returns error: could not find function "knit_print"

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm interested in using ggvis in some markdown documents I'm creating. I know ggvis isn't 'ready' yet and is still in development but whenever I try embedding a ggvis visualization I get the following error:

> Quitting from lines 23-25 (Preview-27581bfac8.Rmd) 
>   Error in knit_print.ggvis(x, options = options) : 
>     could not find function "knit_print"
>   Calls:  ... withVisible -> value_fun -> fun -> knit_print.ggvis
>   Execution halted

I'm using . . . 
R Studio 0.98.976
R 3.1.0
and all my packages are up to date.

Any ideas on what might not be working?

I've done some google searching and examined the ggvis github page with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the current stable version of `ggvis` (i.e. the CRAN version) does not include a `knit_print.ggvis` function.

However, the github repository of ggvis does include this function, see:

https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/master/R/print.R

Therefore I suggest you install the development version:

```
# install the devtools package in case you don't have it already
install.packages('devtools')

# download the development version of ggvis
devtools::install_github("rstudio/ggvis", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

Restart your R session. It should now work.

Out of curiosity, are you also in the data products course?

Comment: I am not in the data products course. I'm just interested in the ggvis package. In theory I like it's syntax and the visualizations it can create more than ggplot, though the latter is much more mature as a package.

Comment: yeah I agree, it makes complete sense to use these two together. These demos in the repo are also interesting: https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/tree/master/demo/rmarkdown